# Diminuir colunas ChartJs Bar Chart

Tags: chartjs

Alguém sabe como posso trabalhar com o tamanho e largura das colunas azuis dentro do gráfico Bar Chart do Chartjs?
Segue imagem exemplo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de deixar as colunas mais finas e mais distantes umas das outras.....

Comment: da uma olhada aqui na documentação da configuração dele mesmo http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-chart-options, caso não tenha da uma olhada na configuração geral http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration

Comment: Eu não consegui encontrar algo semelhante na documentação.. Mas obrigado por enquanto. Se alguém tiver mais alguma ideia, fico agradecido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que foi possível que encontrei na documentação foi mexer na opção do xAxes.

```
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          categoryPercentage: 0.9,
          barPercentage: 0.7
      }],
      ...
    }
```

como pode ser visto nesse exemplo https://jsfiddle.net/smw9949v/1/ alterando os valores entre 0 - 1.

Espero que ajude no que precisa.

Comment: Parece funcionar bem, porém, em meu gráfico não está ocorrendo com sucesso. Vou dar mais uma pesquisada, muito obrigado

Comment: qq coisa da uma olhada nesse http://jsfiddle.net/beehe4eg/ , não sei se tem a ver com versão, mas nesse caso ele usa `categorySpacing`